# How to find out if a Boost header can be used as header-only or not?

Tags: c++, boost

I am using the Boost headers in my project which is compiled by `g++`. I downloaded the Boost source and didn't build it so there are no library files to link.

When I read the Boost website (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/) it says `Boost.Thread` requires its corresponding library, but I am happily using the `<boost/thread/mutex.hpp>(boost::mutex)` header without linking to the Boost thread library.

How do I really tell whether I need to link the corresponding library for using a particular Boost header file or not?

Comment: Compile and link and see if you get unresolved symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Boost documentation states whether a given library is header only or not. If you're using a library which isn't specified header only, and are not linking against the corresponding library, it's undefined behavior.

The fact that it happens to work (or seems to work) isn't really relevant.

Comment: What would be the risk? IMHO if it links out ok... shy from assuming that libboost_thread would override libc functions or something (that would be _evil_) I can't imagine how it would fail or 'be undefined'. Perhaps you mean not portable, supported?

Comment: What would be the risk?  Who knows?  The library authors say you have to do X to use the library, and you don't do X, the library author is exonerated from all guarantees.  Anything that happens, happens: it's not defined.

Comment: I think you are mistaking documentation with _standards specification_. It's just a library. It's just code. It doesn't change the compiler or linker, so we can reason about it :)

Comment: It's a library which has a specification.  Just like C++ has a specification.  You break the rules, you have no guarantees.  (We can talk about what's likely, just as we do for the language.  But it's still undefined behavior.)

Answer (score 3):

In a Terminal:

```
./bootstrap.sh --show-libraries
```

The output shows the list of libraries requiring special build and installation.